# Recalculate Google Sheets until criteria is met

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet and I want to recalculate the formulas until the criteria is met.
I am supplying this demo sheet to show what I want to achieve.

I have a list in Col A.  Im picking 10 random from the list in B.  Checking Unique in C.  Counting number of Unique values in D.

I have a condition set in E1 which test the D1 value.  Above 5 is good.  Under 5 is bad and requires a refresh to recalculate the formulas to obtain a new random list till it goes above 5.

Any suggestion how can I achieve this please?

I thank you in advance for your guidance.

[LINK TO MY SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wOc4_LxMjAGoFM5G6vwIlzzhd8cjf-IWrlyQIw9cqC8/edit?usp=sharing)

**NOTE**: I am not looking for solutions to generate X number of random values from the list.  I want to know if it is possible to implement like a 'while loop' in google sheets.  Recalculate formulas until the condition is fulfilled then stop.

Comment: formulas do not automatically loop and stop looping when a condition is met. you will need an apps script.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: As you do not have an apps script that you need troubleshooting with (and this is not a platform to ask people to do your coding for you), a simple solution is just to enter a character into a random cell, and keep doing it until you have the minimum required. The alternative is for you to write a script then return to seek assistance to fix any problems you may be having with it.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(SORT(A2:A, RANDARRAY(ROWS(A2:A)), 1)), 
 "where Col1 is not null limit 10", )
```

[image]

if you want "above 5" use:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(SORT(A2:A, RANDARRAY(ROWS(A2:A)), 1)), 
 "where Col1 is not null limit 6", )
```

Comment: this formula generates a list of unique random items. the OP previously said (in response to a solution offered that was rejected) that they do not want the original list to be unique as this task is "part of a bigger project", that requires them to first select a completely random list, which is then filtered, and requires refreshing/looping until the minimum (5) are obtained.

Comment: Maybe i need to edit and add this piece on info in my original post.